# Adding a new item to a DataSet, writing it to Access DB

Tags: c#, .net, dataadapter

I'm having an issue with writing back to my Access Database (.accdb) through using a DataAdapter.

Currently, I have a Fill method which fills a DataSet Table up with data. This piece of code is currently sitting within my Form_Load().

```
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'hCAliasDataSet.Topics' table.   You can move, or remove it, as needed.
this.topicsTableAdapter.Fill(this.hCAliasDataSet.Topics);
```

Then I have an cmdAdd_Click() event, this is obviously to add a new row into the Topcis table that sits within the hCAliasDataSet.

```
// Create a new row, append it to Topics table.
DataRow DR;
DR = this.hCAliasDataSet.Tables["Topics"].NewRow();
this.hCAliasDataSet.Tables["Topics"].Rows.Add(DR);
```

Next, I've created some code to caputre the input of **one** of the column values.

```
        // Capture user input
        sTopicName = Interaction.InputBox("Please Enter Topic Name", "Topic Name", null, 100, 100);
        // Set the Topic value for the new Row
        DR["Topic"] = sTopicName;
```

My problem, I'm assuming is here, where I call the dataAdapter to update the Topics table. I manually check the database, and there aren't any new rows created?

```
// Commit the changes back to the hCAlias DataBase (hcalias.accdb).
this.topicsTableAdapter.Update(this.hCAliasDataSet.Topics);
```

Edit: I believe I'm needing to create an INSERT query, for my TableAdapter, would this be correct?

Comment: you can see this blogs. http://www.cnblogs.com/chenping-987123/archive/2010/08/04/1792149.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter should generate the insert statement automatically for you behind the scenes.
Your code looks right, but it's possible that you have a constraint on one of your columns that makes it unable to save. (like a non-nullable column that you didn't specify any data for). But, you'd usually get an exception if there was a constraint that cancelled the insert.

You can try one of these alternatives, but they're basically the same thing:

this.topicsTableAdapter.Update(this.hCAliasDataSet);
this.topicsTableAdapter.Update(DR);
this.topicsTableAdapter.Insert(sTopicName); // add any other columns in here

Comment: Thanks Devin. The insert did the job. Few other things I found I had to change the 'Enforce Constraints' property to True on the DataSet too.

Answer (score 1):

You should call AcceptChanges in your dataset:

```
hCAliasDataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

And then commit to the database with your TableAdapter.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I had AcceptChanges() called already. Unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Update() method just updates existing records, you'll need to use the TableAdapter Insert() method to add a new row. VC# will have created a default Insert() method for you, (which may be overloaded)... but there will be a method that will let you explicitly insert values....

For example...

this.topicsTableAdapter.Insert(int Column1, string Column2 etc etc)

This will create a new row in your database and populate it with the values you specify.

Comment: Thanks Chris, after taking in Devin's reply I looked into the Insert statement VS was creating for me.